# flutter: how to make carousel slider like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 00.0, bottom: 21),
      child: CarouselSlider(
          items: <Widget>[
            for (var i = 0; i < sliderListData.length; i++)
              InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  print(i);
                },
                child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Image.asset(
                            sliderListData[i]['image'],
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight)),
              ),
          ],
          options: CarouselOptions(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 5.8,
              viewportFraction: 0.75,
              padEnds: true,
              initialPage: 0,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              reverse: false,
              autoPlay: false,
              autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 5),
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
              autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              enlargeCenterPage: false,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {})),
    )
```

I want to create slider like this
[image]

but its created like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `enableInfiniteScroll: false,`

```dart
options: CarouselOptions(
    aspectRatio: 16 / 5.8,
    viewportFraction: 0.75,
    padEnds: true,
    initialPage: 0,
    enableInfiniteScroll: false,
    reverse: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 5),
    autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    enlargeCenterPage: false,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {})),
),
```

Comment: yes worked but left side padding have been increased

Comment: do like to remove left padding?

Comment: yes i want to remove padding of lest side

Comment: use `padEnds: false,`